# Excel calculation to roundup number but change to add 9.99 at end

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible with Excel to calculate a column of data to round the number up but round it up to always end in 9.99

- £123.12
- £54.68
- £227.24
- £614.92
- £307.12
- £170.32
- £1,569.82
- £272.84
- £68.40
- £34.19
- £225.72
- £33.44
- £101.84
- £112.86
- £272.84

The above for example is a column for example "D" and I want to take the data of that column and around off so would be like this for example

- £129.99
- £59.99
- £229.99
- £619.99
- £309.99
- £170.32
- £1,569.99
- £279.99
- £69.99
- £39.99
- £229.99
- £33.44
- £109.99
- £119.99
- £279.99

Comment: I assume that £170.32 and £33.44 are typos because they don't seem to round the same way?

Comment: Why are they typos? they are formatted correctly - they are not rounding up at all that is what my question is for. I am wanting to round up as per examples across any decimal amount from 10's, 100's 1000's etc...

Comment: I assumed that the first list was your original values and then the second list is what you want to round to - £170.32 on top list remains £170.32 on bottom list. If you try my formula below it will round to £179.99 - is that what you need?

Comment: Indeed, `£170.32` and `£33.44` are a mystery.  @James, are those ones typo's on your bottom list?  Also, would £123.00 become `£122.99` or `£123.99` ?

Comment: Hi James. I notice that your posts are rather on the chatty side, and I wonder if I could ask you to make them a bit more succinct? I have edited a number of your posts, for the benefit of future readers, and some chatty material is still appearing. We tend to prefer technical-style writing here, so hopes that someone can help, salutations, advance thanks, signatures etc are generally best refrained from. There's a few reference discussions on Meta, [such as this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With original value in `A1` use this formula to Round up as required

`=ROUNDUP(A1+0.01,-1)-0.01`

Comment: I really don't see what your `A1+0.01` is doing. Wouldn't `=ROUNDUP(A1,-1)-0.01` be enough?

Comment: Possibly but if you always want the resulting value to be >= to the original, i.e. rounding UP, then using +0.01 ensures that, otherwise £130.00 rounds to £129.99

Answer (score 1):

To some, the syntax used in CEILING makes more sense.

```
=CEILING(A1, 10)-0.01
```

Note that you are rounding up to the nearest multiple of 10, not to the -1 decimal place which ROUNDUP uses (which for all intents and purposes is 10 anyways).

Comment: Yes I also considered `FLOOR`, i.e. `=FLOOR(A1,10)+9.99` - that gives the same result as my `ROUNDUP` suggestion, yours will round £130.00 to £129.99

Comment: Did the OP ever clarify that the result **must** be larger than the original? I thought that was left hanging (and the solution was explained in your response in any event).

Comment: Agreed - don't know what is preferred by OP, just pointing out the difference

Answer (score 0):

A1 is cell,
-1 number of digit to round off,
9.99 will add in every digit

```
 =ROUND(A2,-1)+9.99
```

Comment: Correct, i did try NDesai but rounded up on a lot of the results incorrectly but did on some

Comment: You can change -1 to 0 it will give you the upper bound of the value.